# Abel-Plana formula for specific function

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, contour-integration, branch-points

Suppose we have the function $f(n) = \sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}$, where $a$ is real. I need to calculate the finite expression
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}f(n) - \int \limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx
$$
By using the Abel-Plana formula, I obtain
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}f(n) = \int \limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx + \frac{a}{2} + i\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(ix) - f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx
$$
How to show that the last integral is
$$
i\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(ix) - f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx = -2\int\limits_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}dx}{e^{2\pi x}-1}?
$$
The problem is with the branching point $x = \pm ia$, which leads to appearance of the additional phase for $f(ix)$ for $x>a$, and for $f(ix)$ it is $+i$, while for $f(-ix)$ it is $-\pi$.

Comment: Similarly: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387950/how-to-evaluate-infinite-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-sqrtb2n2-e-an

Comment: the sum in question diverge if we interpret it in a classical manner.. so what do have in mind exactly?

Comment: @tired : instead of the sum, we can consider its finite part:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}f(n) - \int \limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx
$$
The only remained terms in the Abel-Plana formula are finite.

Comment: ok fine... next question: where do you get the $e^{2\pi f(x)}$ in the denominator from? usually we have just $e^{2\pi x}$ (see wiki for instance)?

Comment: @tired : sorry, this is a misprint.

Comment: then you should remove it...

Comment: @tired : it is already done.

Comment: ok, next problem what can we do to handle the singulatiry at $x=0$ of your target integral?

Comment: @tired : I'm sorry for such mistakes, this is again a misprint. The correct lower limit should be $a$ instead of $0$...

Comment: Are you also aware that your target function $f$ doesn't fit the usual criteria to apply abel-plana? we therefor have to be really careful to make sense out of the outlined calculations

Comment: shouldne be $$ \sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}} $$

Comment: @tired : it turns out that the extra contributions in the Abel-Plana formula coming from the bypassing of the branching points tend to zero.

Comment: @JoseGarcia : it seems that it shouldn't.

Comment: I would rephrase and ask for a closed form (if existing) of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left( f(x)-f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\right)\,dx$ with $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$, instead of asking for the value of a clearly divergent series.